# Which devices does clBuildProgram build for, if we pass NULL to device_list parameter?

Tags: opencl

`clBuildProgram` allows one to give a list of devices to build the program for. That's the reason of the `num_devices` and `device_list` parameters in the declaration:

```
cl_int clBuildProgram(cl_program program, cl_uint num_devices, const cl_device_id *device_list, const char *options, void (CL_CALLBACK *pfn_notify)(cl_program program, void *user_data), void *user_data)
```

Now what happens, if we use it like this?

```
cl_int clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, ...
```

1. Does it build for all devices in the PC?
2. Does it build for only those devices I have created the context for? (I mean the context I used when I created `program` with `clCreateProgramWithSource`.)

The documentation says:

> **device_list:** A pointer to a list of devices associated with program. If device_list is NULL value, the program executable is built for all devices associated with program for which a source or binary has been loaded. If device_list is a non-NULL value, the program executable is built for devices specified in this list for which a source or binary has been loaded.

I think the phrasing is a bit complicated here, but from that, I guess number 2. Is that right?

---

I am asking because in case of number 1, I would need to pass a device list to this function in order to avoid superfluous compilation for all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) is correct. Compilation is constrained to only the devices associated with the program's context. This cannot be every single device in the system unless the context was created using every single device.